# regular expression for urls to rewrite

Tags: url-rewriting, iis-7, iis-8

I need to write rewrite rules in IIS that will redirect to https://example.com/xml.

So
case 1: https://example.com/test

case 2: https://example.com/[country-lang-token]/test

(e.g https://example.com/en-us/test and
          https://example.com/fr-fr/test)

should be redirect to  https://example.com/xml.

I know how to write rewrite rules but stuck due to regular expression.

Answer (score 1):

Your rule should be like this:

```
<rule name="Redirect to xml" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/test$" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/\w{2}-\w{2}/test$" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="/xml" />
</rule>
```

First condition is for case 1 url `https://example.com/test`
Second condition is for case 2 `https://example.com/[country-lang-token]/test` where `[country-lang-token]` is string in format `{two_letters}-{two_letters}`